# Does "Go on" mean "depend on"?

Tags: meaning

> An even stronger form of skepticism is possible. Similar arguments
>   seem to show that you don't know anything even about your own past
>   existence and experiences, since all you have to go on are the present
>   contents of your mind, including memory impressions

What does it all mean? Thomas Nagel

What does the word "go on" mean?

I think it means "depend on" Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

I believe 'go on' in this case is similar to saying 'continue with'.

It doesn't substitute exactly but the meaning of the phrase 'all you have to go on' is similar to saying 'all the information you have to work with'.

Comment: In colliins dictionary, #10
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/go-on

"If you talk about the information you have to go on, you mean the information you have available to base an opinion or judgment on."

Comment: Yes, or in other words, information, as restricted by some arbitary limitations, which you can use to **continue** something (whether that be forming an opinion, a judgement or making a decision).